# Entire QGIS lost after crash

Tags: qgis, desktop-gis

I lost an entire project when QGIS crashed. The project file has disappeared from the folder it has been sitting. Is there any way of recovering it?

Comment: That's a bit strange, I have never heard of a crash deleting files from the disk.

Comment: I have been backing up manually, tha backup was not up to date. Have now installed auto save. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to recover it from the last backup you made (you do make regular backups?).

To avoid losing an entire sessions work in the unlikely event of a crash you should install the `auto save` plugin which automatically saves a copy of your project at regular intervals.